# Programatically enter Command line window

Tags: command-line, command

I have bind `q` to `:qa` that hides `q:`.

Is there a command to enter the Command Line Window that is not `q:`?

How to access the Command Line Window without typing: `q:`?

Comment: Press `:` to enter a vim command. Or are you talking in vimscript, or from invoking vim from the command line or a shell script?

Comment: I want to launch the Command line window (`q:`) from a Command

Comment: I would be interested to understand what you mean by boud `q` to `:qa`. Do you mean `cnoremap`, do you mean `cnoreabbrev` do you add test about the position of `q` in the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence `:`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> will do (`:help cedit`). Also `:normal! q:`.

Answer (score 2):

You could bind something else to open the command-line window using a `noremap`:

```
:nnoremap Q: q:
```

See `:help :noremap`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
:call feedkeys("q:", "n")
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
:norm! q:
```

The `!` makes normal skip the custom mapping.

Comment: This was part of the answer I posted.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry :)